# Comparable Alternative to Messenger Bag

Tags: bags, messenger-bags

Hunting the internet for months for an alternative of this bag (which unfortunately isn't available for purchase anymore): http://www.alkr.com/urban-messenger.html

I searched on Amazon, Ebags, Google, Codura Corporate Website, but can't seem to find something satisfactory.

Requirements:

1. Solid "Codura" fabric or comparable (no leather, black, low key design)
2. Not a dedicated messenger bag
3. Structured, thoughtful compartment design (not one big compartment, fits 13" laptop somehow, medium sized)
4. No floppy bottom

Any suggestion are welcomed and please don't recommend the common choices like Timbuk2 Messenger. Violates at least points 2), 4) ;-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "no floppy bottom"? Are you actually wanting some kind of a rigid plate in the bottom of the bag?

Comment: No, I don't mean rigid but I had a few bags which couldn't even hold a few documents without deforming the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options for this I can't list them all, here are a few good ones.

[Mission Workshop](http://missionworkshop.com/products/bags/messenger/) has very refined and expensive bags, very full featured multi purpose bags.

[Rickshaw Bagworks](http://www.rickshawbags.com/laptop-messenger-bags/laptop-bag.html) has several commuter bags you may want to check out.

[Chrome Bags](http://www.chromebagsstore.com/bags/laptop-bags.html)  has lots of laptop bags in addition to their standard messenger bags.

Comment: Just ordered "the monty" from Mission Workshop, seems to be a good alternative to me. Thanks for the tips. Maybe I will supplement it with something like the Freitag F17 JOE, which seems a little bit more casual without the bike.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, nothing can truly compare to a messenger bag. However, you can definitely find a reasonable balance between quality and price. Look for something that will suit your needs as a commuter or a messenger. As a messenger myself, I find that a medium sized bag with adjustable length on the clips (for holding packages too big to actually put in the bag) will work perfectly. Try to find one on any off-brand purchasing sites like eBay, craigslist, etc. The medium sizes of Timbuk2, a brand that I personally prefer, will generally run about $70 used plus shipping. Keep in mind, messenger bags are made to be durable, so it is acceptable to buy them used. Generally, a messenger will never actually sell his bag. Value-wise, they come second to the bike, which is the messenger's livelihood, so you are really buying from the average commuter who's bag doesn't take as much of a beating, so buying a used bag will be an okay option.

Good luck and happy hunting!